# I want to fetch the latest id in flask mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python

When I run the following query, it gives me the first id, I want the last id and I want the data in that id, how can I do it?

```
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
sorgu = "Select * From site2"
result = cursor.execute(sorgu) 
if result > 0:
    articles = cursor.fetchone()        
    return render_template("site.html",articles = articles)
else:
    return render_template("site.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First retrieve the max ID from the table (assuming your IDs are incrementing upward as rows are added. This means the largest is the last one), then use it in your final query

```
sorgu = "SELECT * FROM site2 WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM site2)"
```

If you have a timestamp column in your data base you could do `MAX(timestap)` to get the latest ID as well